# Display QMessageBox with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, qt, arguments, qstring, qmessagebox

I'm using the Qt framework and I'm a little rusty with it.

I have two QStrings `first` and `last`

I want to display them in a `QMessageBox` but don't know how to include multiple arguments.

This is what I have to code it with on argument:

```
QMessageBox::information(0, "Full Name", QString("%1 %2").arg(first));
```

How do I get the other argument (`last`) included in that output?

Comment: `QMessageBox::information(0, "Full Name", QString("%1 %2").arg(first).arg(last));`

Comment: Oh, that simple?  Sweet thanks!

Comment: It can be as simple as `first + " " + last`. How could you not figure it out?

Comment: Wanted to learn it the args method so I can answer it properly if that comes up in an exam I'm writing soon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the arg()s return a QString so the following should work:

```
QMessageBox::information(0, "Full Name", QString("%1 %2").arg(first).arg(last));
```

For more information, you can check the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes should do something like that:

```
QMessageBox::information(0, "Full Name", QString("%1 %2").arg(first, last));
```