# How to add variable value in Qt QMessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmessagebox

```
printf("This machine calculated all prime numbers under %d %d times in %d 
  seconds\n", MAX_PRIME, NUM_OF_CORES, run_time);
```

I want this output to be printed in `QMessageBox` text Box.

I have gone through `QMessageBox` documentation didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display QMessageBox with multiple arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062868/display-qmessagebox-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must fill `QString` for you `QMessageBox`. You can do it with method `arg` of [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html). Then you can show message box with static method [information](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#information) of QMessageBox. In your case code will be:

```
QMessageBox::information(nullptr/*or parent*/, "Title",  
    QString("This machine calculated all prime numbers under %1 %2 times in %3 seconds")
    .arg(MAX_PRIME).arg(NUM_OF_CORES).arg(run_time));
```

Answer (score 4):

`QMessageBox` has nothing for it because it's none of its business - it just displays strings as you passed them. However, `QString` does provide methods for formatting data replacing placeholders using the `arg` method:

```
QMessageBox::information(parent,
     QString("This machine calculated all prime numbers under %1 %2 times in %3 seconds")
         .arg(MAX_PRIME)
         .arg(NUM_OF_CORES)
         .arg(run_time), "Message title");
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#argument-formats

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg